# Simultaneous equation with summation and square - how to solve?

Tags: geometry, summation, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

- $\mathbf{p}$ is a vector with dimension: $x \times 1$
- $\mathbf{d}$ is a vector with dimension: $1 \times y$
- $\mathbf{V}$ is a matrix with dimension: $x \times y$
- $y \geq x$
- $\mathbf{d}$ and $\mathbf{V}$ are known.

Aaaaand:
$$
\mathbf{d}_{1y} = \sum ^{x}_{i=1} \left( \mathbf{p}_{i1}-\mathbf{V}_{iy} \right )^2
$$

<sup><sup>(I'm not sure if the subscript '1' is required for $\mathbf{d}$ and $\mathbf{p}$, please ignore them if it's not the usual notation)</sup></sup>

I need to solve for $\mathbf{p}$.

---

I've tried to put the vectors into the same dimension as $\mathbf{V}$ to see if I could use algebra to nut it out, but the square in particular made we wary of the result, (let alone the summation).

How is $\mathbf{p}$ pulled out of the summation and square? (i.e. how do I solve for $\mathbf{p}$?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix $V$ can be written as $y$ column vectors $v_j$, each of dimension $x$:
$$
V = (v_1, \dotsc, v_y)
$$
Then the $j$-th component of vector $d$ is the scalar product of the difference vector $p-v_j$ with itself, which is its Euclidean norm squared:
$$
d_j = (p - v_j)^2 = \lVert p - v_j \rVert_2^2 
= \sum_{i=1}^x (p_i - v_{ij})^2 = r_j^2 \quad (j \in \{1,\dotsc,y\})
$$
These are spheres with center at vector $v_j$ and radius $r_j = \sqrt{d_j}$.

So $p$ is an element of the intersection of the above $y$ spheres in $x$ dimensions.

This seems to be a generalization of the [trilateration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilateration) problem.

**Example:**

$$
V = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 3\\
2 & 4
\end{pmatrix}
\quad
d = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
4
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Then
$$
d_1 = 1 = (p_1 - 1)^2 + (p_2 - 2)^2 \\
d_2 = 4 = (p_1 - 3)^2 + (p_2 - 4)^2
$$

[image: example]

The circles in 2D can have zero, one, two or infinite many intersection points, where the last case is two congruent circles.

In 3D we have zero or one intersection points or a circle of intersection or congruence.

In higher dimensions I do not know the cases.

**Formulation as Non-Linear Least Squares Problem:**

In presence of errors one define the residues
$$
e_j(p) = d_j - \sum_{i=1}^x (p_i - v_{ij})^2
$$
and the task is to find a vector $p$ which minimizes
$$
S(p) = e^2 = \sum_{j=1}^y e_i^2
$$
This seems to be a [non-linear least squares problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-linear_least_squares).

Comment: Hello, thanks for looking at my question - much appreciated! But unless I'm mistaking by some nice math magic (above me) that you've done (?), I feel like I need to point out that $\mathbf{V}$ is a matrix with dimension: $x \times y$ - also, there is the summation - how are they dealt with here?

Comment: Thanks so much for working in this, it's really interesting to see parts that make me go 'ahh, yes, true!'. Pretty neat seeing a potential answer forming in front of me :)

Comment: In the application, x will be in the order of 10's - I have arbitrary control over y so I can force the system to be over-defined. A colleague after a quick look suggested least squares...

Comment: I added a pointer. I would expect this to be a standard problem of some kind, spherical constraints are quite natural.

Comment: Looking at the actual problem again, I see that the circles will never quite all align (it's in code and there will be rounding errors etc.). My orginal thought was in taking for instance x=2 and y=3 I could end up with:  6 solutions, 3 of which are 'close', I could find their centroid for instance - or 2 or 6 imaginary solutions (non-intersection) where I could increase all the radii (in equal multiplicative measure) until I get 6 real solutions as before...  But then, I think that's just a bodge, least squares as has been suggested looks like the way forward :)

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40660/trilateration-algorithm-for-n-amount-of-points